# Trying to filter out all strings except one in variable

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a macro that is supposed to select all of column "F" from row 6 and down. It then filters that selection so that all but one variable (xOutValue) is still shown. It will then delete the visible rows, then remove the filter. The result should show only the remaining rows with variable xOutValue. Although I get no error, the Autofilter is not filtering out anything. All variables still remain in the selected cells.
Here is the code..

```
' Filters and deletes all rows without the most common code(xOutValue) in column "F".
    Range(Cells(12, 6), Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(12, 6), Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=("<>" & xOutValue)
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

The variables in the selected cells are unpredictable, so I cannot create a table of them. If anyone has a better way to do this I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Comments within provide some pointers, try this out:

```
Sub filter()

' Filters and deletes all rows without the most common code(xOutValue) in column "F".

    'Try to avoid selects. Using With (range) is a better option generally
    'Range(Cells(12, 6), Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)).Select

Dim xoutvalue As String
xoutvalue = "abcd"

' using cells(12,6) would return anything row 12 and beyond, so we do (6,6). 
''However I chose this after running into some issues. 
'''Since we define field as well we can just choose the 6th column (f) and a row count

    With ActiveSheet.Rows(6 & ":" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count)
        .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=("<>" & xoutvalue)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    End With
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    

End Sub
```

Comment: You are correct Arktik. Cells(12,6) would return anything from row 12 and down. That's actually what I'm trying to do (I misspoke earlier).

The code you provided now filters EVERYTHING out, including 'xOutValue'. I'm left with no data.
The code before my problem area sorts through "F", finding the most common string and assigning it to 'xOutValue', That part works fine. It then gives the user an opportunity to change that value before finally using 'xOutValue' in the code I posted, which is intended to clear out any rows where the value in column F of that row does not match 'xOutValue'

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard my question. I found the problem and it was not related to my code, but rather the data.

It turns out that the data I was using in Column F had a space in front of every entry. Somehow, even though my code should not have cared, the space was affecting the filter criteria. As soon as I removed that leading space from xOutValue, everything worked.